# How to check fb app is installed on iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

```
BOOL isInstalled = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://"]]

if (isInstalled) {

} else {

}
```

Above code working fine with iPhone but not iPad.

Comment: Are you testing on a real iPad? Is the Facebook app installed on the iPad? Is there any output in the debug console when you run this code through the Xcode debugger on your iPad?

Comment: What versions of iOS are each device running?

Comment: what is your ipad version and once verify in manually,  fb is installed in your ipad or not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you'll need to 'whitelist' the URL by adding the following to your `Info.plist` file

```xml
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fb</string>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

and check

```
 if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://"]]) {
    // Facebook app is installed
}else
{
 // not installed
 }
```

Comment: Since the OP states that the code works on an iPhone, it must be assumed this has all been done already. And why add all of those schemes when the app only uses the `fb` scheme?

Comment: @rmaddy - I agree bro may  be if fb not installed in ipad or may installed the `fbapi://", @"fb-messenger-api://", @"fbauth2://", @"fbshareextension://`  this we need to check

Comment: No, this app is only calling `canOpenURL:` on the `fb` scheme. Therefore only that scheme needs to be whitelisted.

Comment: @rmaddy - ok , Sure I modify my answer, before I take the additional information from questioner

Comment: <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fb</string>
</array> .  works for me.Thanks.

Comment: @rmaddy - bro, the problem is iOS verson if questioner added the FB in whitelist now working fine bro

Comment: Please help me again. After clicking on "login in with facebook" button it is navigating to safari and not to facebook app in ipad.iPad ios version is 9.3.2 and Facebook sdk version is 2.0 (older one),is that  the reason why it is navigating to safari.

Comment: @shaileshParkhi - no the new function in iOS, after ios 9 FB login always open the safari it redirect to safari

Comment: Update FBSDK to latest version If there is no FB app then it will open in app browser which using Safari View Controller. also your app not get rejected when you submit to review